# Meanstack io packages uninstall

Tags: javascript, mean.io

The core directory under the packages directory contains

- admin
- articles
- swagger
- circles
- system
- users

and Custom directory contains

- i18n
- themes
- mail-templates

I want to start my app from scratch what all packages i need to delete completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages core are importan, but you can delete the package "articles" without problems that is only for demo, into "Custom" directory you can uninstall all packages, but you must consider than in the package "themes" is configured the main style for the page, you can override it without problems in another custom package.

For uninstall "Custom" packages you should execute this command:

```
$ mean uninstall i18n
$ mean uninstall mail-template
$ mean uninstall theme
```

And for install a new package you should execute this command:

```
$ mean package new-custom-package
```

Comment: what about circles admin and users package are they much important